# How do I reference a static function to pass as a parameter?

Tags: c++, scope, compiler-errors

I have a static function `callback`:

```
static SCDynamicStoreCallBack callback( [params] ){ ... }
```

In `main`, I'm calling

```
createIPAddressListChangeCallbackSCF(callback, manager, &storeRef, &sourceRef);
```

This function requires a callback function to be passed as a parameter. However when I try and compile, I get the error

```
error: ‘callback’ was not declared in this scope
```

`callback` is declared in the root of the file. How should I be referencing it from `main`?

Comment: Declaration/definition of the `callback()` is visible to `main()`. If yes then [it should work](http://ideone.com/3HWxo).

Comment: reproduce the problem in a teeny tiny little program. if that doesn't itself help you see what's wrong, post that minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that callback() is not defined in the same file as main().

static functions (and variables) aren't visible across files, even if there's a prototype or extern declaration. So, either callback() has to move to the same file as main(), or it has to lose its static'ness.

If both functions are in the same file, either callback() has to be defined first or there must be a prototype/declaration of it before main().

Comment: `callback` was declared after `main`.

Comment: @iammilind Yup, I'm a Java programmer trying to write C++, this is not the first, or worst thing that's gone wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable):

> In the C programming language, static is used with global variables
>   and functions to set their scope to the containing file. In local
>   variables, static is used to store the variable in the statically
>   allocated memory instead of the automatically allocated memory. While
>   the language does not dictate the implementation of either type of
>   memory, statically allocated memory is typically reserved in data
>   segment of the program at compile time, while the automatically
>   allocated memory is normally implemented as a transient call stack.

This means, that the `static` function is only visible in the file it is declared. If that is not the same file where you call `createIPAddressListChangeCallbackSCF` you run into that exact error. Try it by removing the `static` keyword.

**EDIT:** also add the function definition somewhere readable in your `main`.

Comment: I get the same issue without the static keyword. `createIPAddressListChangeCallbackSCF` is a library call.

Comment: Try to make a function declaration like `SCDynamicStoreCallBack callback( [params] );` an put it in your `main` file. This should work.